# Code is working in jsfiddle ,but not in localserver

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

Please help me to fix this...

i have a link with the code http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/14/ its working fine in jsfiddle... but if i put the same thing in localhost its not working any specific reason?i also checked javascripts and jquery everything is embeded correctly(other jsfiddle code works fine)......

can anyone guide me on how to place this code

```
$('q.clickMe1').click(function () {
// find first of following DIV siblings
// with class "textBox" and toggle it

$(this).nextAll('div.sri1:first').show();
$('div.sri1:visible').not($(this).nextAll('div.sri1:first')).toggle();
});
```

html code

```
<q class="clickMe1">Hire</q>
<br />
<div class="sri1"> - This text will be toggled</div>

 <q class="clickMe1">Manage</q>
 <br />
 <div class="sri1"> - This text will be toggled 2</div>
```

Comment: which error occurs or what is the problem ?

Comment: did you wrap your code in a `document.ready` handler?  jsfiddle does that for you by default.

Comment: Is your above javascript inside a `$(document).ready()` block? - lol @Alnitak.  Nearly synchronised!

Comment: no errors but nothing will happen when we click on "text1" or "text2" ,,i think script is not running bcos in jsfiddle we are running jqery1.72 on load .... but how can i do it in my php page? i have put script code in <head><script> script code</script></head> and html in <body> session

Comment: If you change the select box to no wrap, then it won't work in jsFiddle. It's just a convinience from jsFiddle to wrap it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsFiddle is wrapping the code in `onload` by default that's why it's working. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/19/) is fiddle where it's not working since I disabled the onload wrapping.

To make it work for you, wrap it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('q.clickMe1').click(function () {
        // find first of following DIV siblings
        // with class "textBox" and toggle it
        $(this).nextAll('div.sri1:first').show();
        $('div.sri1:visible').not($(this).nextAll('div.sri1:first')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Assuming you are using jQuery 1.7 or above, you can avoid this wrapping and use `.on()` instead like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'q.clickMe1', function () {
    //...your code here
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTYa2/20/) - no onload and still working.

Comment: oh my god how come i missed this.... sorry guyzzz for bothering you.....its working fine now.....thanks for your clear explanation ..shadow

Comment: @Archer "Users who have not set a display name in their profile are not notified" ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)) - anyway judging his "accept history" I believe he will accept it sooner or later. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the info - I didn't know that.  I'll save my breath in future ;)